# Where to add the Custom RPC types in polkadot-js/apps directory?

Tags: polkadot-js, apps

In the [Custom RPC types](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/rpc.custom/) docs it explains *how* to create the types within the API promise, but it doesn't explain *where* to add it within the polkadot-js/apps repo, which is understandable because the docs are not specifically for adding to the apps repo. However, it would be useful and helpful to get guidance on it, because the repo is spectacular but also occasionally overwhelming.

Up to this point, I have decorated rpc methods and added it to `typeBundle.ts`, but it still not available as an `api.rpc.<firstModule>.<secondModule>` call, like the screenshot below.

Apart from typesBundle.ts, where do I also need to add it as a property so that it satisfies the `DecoratedRpc...`?

[image]

Comment: the answer is to add in the RpcInterface area in a fork off typegen https://github.com/polkadot-js/docs/tree/master/docs/api/examples/promise/typegen. Thereafter import the types into the clone of your polkadot-js/apps.